Mellin transform of the power of the reciprocal gamma function
Let $$f(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma^n(z)}\text{, $n>0$: integer, and $z>0$}.$$ How to obtain the Mellin transform of $f(z)$? I couldn't find it in any table of Mellin transforms. thanks in advance.
My try: according to http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/pdf/1407.5983.pdf
The series expansion is
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k z^k,
$$
where $a_k=\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi k!}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\, \mbox{Im}\{(\log t-i\pi)^k\}\,dt$. Now could we apply the multinomial theorem? That is,
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma^n(z)}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k z^k\right)^n=\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j z^j,
$$
but we need to work out the coefficients $c_j$, which I am not sure.
Then, the Mellin transform would be
$$
M[f(z)]=\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j \int_0^\infty z^{s+j-1}dz,
$$
then the integral above will converge only for a few values of $s+j$. Any ideas? thanks.

You compute $\int_0^\infty f(z) z^{s-1},\mathrm{d}z$.  You won't get very far because the result is not expressible in recognizable functions for any $n$.

I've never even been able to find a result for the Mellin transform of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$.

For $n=1$, MathWorld has the “Mu function”.

@ТymaGaidash The Mu function has the same problem as the Nu function, $\frac{x^t}{t}$ is not the same thing as $t^{s-1}$.

@StevenClark $x$ can be set to $1$

The Mellin transform of $z^j$ is a distribution, i.e. $$\mathcal{M}_z\leftz^j\right=2 \pi, \delta (i (j+s))$$ so perhaps you should consider a representation for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z}$ other than a power series.

@ТymaGaidash Ok, so I think you mean $$\mathcal{M}_t\left\frac{1}{\Gamma (t)}\right=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{t^{s-1}}{\Gamma (t)} , dt=\Gamma (s+1), \mu (1,s).$$ The Wolfram MathWorld article only gives a name to an integral and provides no insight into its evaluation, but perhaps some of the references in the Wolfram MathWorld article provide some insight into evaluation of the integral.

The Mellin transform of a product is the convolution $$\mathcal{M}zf(z) g(z)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits{c-i \infty }^{c+i \infty } \hat{f}(r), \hat{g}(s-r) , dr$$ of their Mellin transforms $\hat{f}(r)$ and $\hat{g}(r)$, so perhaps this relationship can be leveraged to iteratively derive the Mellin transforms of powers of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$ from the Mellin transform of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$ assuming one can derive the latter.

This isn't a complete answer as it only addresses the case $n=1$ and doesn't provide a closed-form representation, but I believe the case $n=1$ is the most important and I'm not sure there is any closed-form representation.

Formulas (1) to (4) in this answer below are refinements of formulas for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ and its Mellin and Laplace transforms I posted in this question on Math StackExchange about 5 years ago. These refinements extend the range of convergence and improve convergence at modest evaluation limits.

I believe $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ can be evaluated as
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}=\lim_\limits{\substack{N, f\to\infty} \\ M(N)=0} \left(e^2\, 2^{-s} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left(1+n^s \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(\frac{1}{n+i \pi f n}\right)^s+\left(\frac{1}{n-i \pi f n}\right)^s\right)\\+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f n-1} \left(\left(\frac{1}{n+i \pi k}\right)^s+\left(\frac{1}{n-i \pi k}\right)^s\right)\right)\right)\right),\ \Re(s)>0\tag{1}$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, the parameter $f$ in the upper evaluation limit of the inner sum over $k$ is assumed to be a positive integer.

A conditional convergence requirement of formula (1) above (and formulas (2) to (4) below which are derived from formula (1) above) is $M(N)=0$ where $M(N)=\sum\limits_{n\le N}\mu(n)$ is the Mertens function. Note the condition $M(N)=0$ can be met for arbitrarily large magnitudes of $N$ since the Mertens function has an infinite number of integer zeros. See https://oeis.org/A028442 for the zeros of the Mertens function. Formulas (5) to (8) following Figure (4) below eliminate this conditional convergence requirement.

I believe formula (1) above can be analytically extended as
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}=\lim_\limits{\substack{N\to\infty} \\ M(N)=0} \left(e^2\, 2^{-s} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left(1+\frac{n^s}{\pi^s} \left((-i)^s \zeta\left(s,1-\frac{i n}{\pi}\right)+i^s \zeta\left(s,\frac{i n}{\pi}+1\right)\right)\right)\right),\ s\in\mathbb{C}\tag{2}$$
where $\zeta(s,a)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function.

Formula (1) above leads to the following formulas for the Mellin and Laplace transforms of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$.

$$\mathcal{M}_z\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\right](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} z^{s-1}\,dz\\=\lim_\limits{\substack{N, f\to\infty} \\ M(N)=0} \left(e^2\, \Gamma(s) \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left(\log^{-s}(2)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log^{-s}(2 (1+i \pi f))+\log^{-s}(2 (1-i \pi f))\right)\\+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f n-1} \left(\log^{-s}\left(\frac{2 (n+i \pi k)}{n}\right)+\log^{-s}\left(\frac{2 (n-i \pi k)}{n}\right)\right)\right)\right),\quad\Re(s)>-1\tag{3}$$

$$\mathcal{L}_z\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\right](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} e^{-s z}\,dz\\=\lim_\limits{\substack{N, f\to\infty} \\ M(N)=0} \left(e^2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left(\frac{1}{s+\log(2)}+\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{s+\log(2 (1-i \pi f))}+\frac{1}{s+\log(2 (1+i \pi f))}\right)\\+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f n-1} \left(\frac{1}{s+\log\left(\frac{2 (n-i \pi k)}{n}\right)}+\frac{1}{s+\log\left(\frac{2 (n+i \pi k)}{n}\right)}\right)\right)\right),\quad\Re(s)>-\log(2)\tag{4}$$

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (1) for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ where formula (1) is evaluated at $f=8$ and $N=39$ (note $M(39)=0$).

Figure (1): Illustration of formula (1) for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ in orange overlaid on $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ in blue

Figure (2) below illustrates formula (2) for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ where formula (2) is evaluated at $N=39$.

Figure (2): Illustration of formula (2) for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ in orange overlaid on $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ in blue

Figure (3) below illustrates the Mellin transform integral in formula (3) above evaluated using numeric integration in blue overlaid by the series in formula (3) above in orange where the series is evaluated at $f=8$ and $N=39$.

Figure (3): Illustration of formula (3) for the Mellin transform of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$

Figure (4) below illustrates the Laplace transform integral in formula (4) above evaluated using numeric integration in blue overlaid by the series in formula (4) above in blue where the series is evaluated at $f=8$ and $N=39$.

Figure (4): Illustration of formula (4) for the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$

Formulas (1) to (4) above require the upper evaluation limit $N$ in the outer sums over $n$ to be selected such that $M(N)=0$ where $M(N)=\sum\limits_{n\le N} \mu(n)$ is the Mertens function, but formulas (5) to (8) below eliminate this conditional convergent requirement.

I believe $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ can be evaluated as
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}=\lim_\limits{N, f\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2} e^2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\text{nMax}} \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(2^{-s}+\frac{1}{2} \left((2+2 i \pi  f)^{-s}+(2-2 i \pi  f)^{-s}\right)\\+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)-1} (-1)^k \left(\left(2+\frac{i \pi k}{2 n-1}\right)^{-s}+\left(2-\frac{i \pi k}{2 n-1}\right)^{-s}\right)\right)\right),\quad\Re(s)>0\tag{5}$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius Function and the parameter $f$ in the upper evaluation limit of the inner sum over $k$ is assumed to be a positive integer.

I believe formula (5) above for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ can be analytically extended as
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}=\lim_\limits{N\to\infty} \left(e^2\, 2^{-s-1} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(1+\\\pi^{-s} (2 n-1)^s \left(e^{\frac{i \pi s}{2}} \left(\zeta\left(s,1+\frac{i (2 n-1)}{\pi}\right)-\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i (2 n-1)}{\pi}\right)\right)\\+e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi s} \left(\zeta\left(s,1-\frac{i (2 n-1)}{\pi}\right)-\zeta\left(s,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i (2 n-1)}{\pi}\right)\right)\right)\right)\right),\quad s\in\mathbb{C}\tag{6}$$
where $\zeta(s,a)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function.

Formula (5) above leads to the following formulas for the Mellin and Laplace transforms of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$.

$$\mathcal{M}_z\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\right](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} z^{s-1}\,dz\\=\lim_\limits{N, f\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2} e^2\, \Gamma(s) \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(\log^{-s}(2)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log^{-s}(2+2 i \pi f)+\log^{-s}(2-2 i \pi f)\right)\\+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)-1} (-1)^k \left(\log^{-s}\left(2+\frac{i \pi k}{2 n-1}\right)+\log^{-s}\left(2-\frac{i \pi k}{2 n-1}\right)\right)\right)\right),\quad\Re(s)>-1\tag{7}$$

$$\mathcal{L}_z\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\right](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} e^{-s z}\,dz\\=\lim_\limits{N, f\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2} e^2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(\frac{1}{s+\log (2)}+\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{s+\log(2-2 i \pi f)}+\frac{1}{s+\log(2+2 i \pi f)}\right)\\+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)-1} (-1)^k \left(\frac{1}{s+\log\left(2-\frac{i \pi k}{2 n-1}\right)}+\frac{1}{s+\log\left(2+\frac{i \pi k}{2 n-1}\right)}\right)\right)\right),\quad\Re(s)>-\log(2)\tag{8}$$

Formulas (5) to (8) above converge similar to formulas (1) to (4) above, so I won't bother to illustrate them since their evaluations look similar to Figures (1) to (4) above. But formulas (2) and (6) above can be used to evaluate $\Gamma(s)$ via the relationship
$$\Gamma(s)=\frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi s)}\, \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-s)},\quad s\in\mathbb{C}\land s\ne 0\land -s\notin\mathbb{N}\tag{9}$$
and Figure (5) below illustrates $\Gamma(s)$ in blue overlaid by formula (9) above where formula (6) for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ evaluated at $N=25$ is used to evaluate the $\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-s)}$ term in formula (9) above.

Figure (5): Illustration of formula (9) for $\Gamma(s)$ using formula (6) for $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}$ to evaluate the $\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-s)}$ term in formula (9)
